# Magento set product sku as prefix of order id

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, increment-id

I know that, Magento has it's own way of generating order ids for orders placed through it.

Instead of the default way, I want to set *product sku* as the prefix for *order-id*s and keep order increment id as it is.

Is there any way to achieve this in Magento?

Comment: What should happen if your customer purchase more than one product?

Comment: we are allowing only one product..user can't buy more than one product at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the order ID is an integer value. Example:

- order_id = 1
- increment_id = "1000000001"

It might be possible the other way around, though. You can create your own **increment model** for orders to define arbitrary logic for the increment id.

You will need to implement `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Interface` with the method `getNextId()`.

It is not intended to access the actual order data at this point, but since it is called during order creation, you should be able to call `Mage::registry('current_order')` and look through the order items and their SKU.

Further reading: [Magento Tutorial: How to Use Increment Models to Generate IDs (or SKUs)](http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/12/magento-tutorial-use-increment-models-generate-ids-or-skus/)